# Does instantiating a specific variable make a difference? C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was following a tutorial, writing this code here:

```
public class Board : MonoBehaviour
{

//A reference to the cell prefab that will be created. 
public GameObject mCellPrefab;

public Cell[,] mAllCells = new Cell[9, 9];

public void Create()
{
    for (int y = 1; y <= 8; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 8; x++)
 

       {
                GameObject newCell = Instantiate(mCellPrefab, transform);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the class, we have a variable of a GameObject. Which I think in Unity is just like an object. Then later down the line, we instantiate it.

I was just curious if there is actually any reason to use the actual object "mCellPrefab" and not just do something like this for example:

```
            GameObject newCell = Instantiate(new GameObject, transform);
```

Do we actually gain anything from using the class specific variable, versus just the base one, assuming its just a basic building block object?

Comment: I think I understood as soon as I posted my question, atleast in the Unity context. The reason we dont want to just a new Object is we set the GameObject as a PreFab in the inspector, and that is what will get instantiated.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason.